# map returns error while long form succeeds swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to map a response but it gives error when I try the short form which I do not understand why.

this works fine

```
.map { (responseArray)  in
                (responseArray.data?.map({ (identiferResponse) in
                    IdentifiersCellViewModel(with: identiferResponse)
                }))!
            }
```

But when I do this it gives an error

```
.map { $0.data.map { IdentifiersCellViewModel(with: $0) } }
```

error

> Cannot convert value of type '[IdentifierResponse]?' to expected
>   argument type 'IdentifierResponse'

how can this be resolved or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
let res = arr.compactMap { $0.data?.map { IdentifiersCellViewModel(with: $0) } }
```

Answer (score 3):

It should have been:

```
.map { $0.data?.map { IdentifiersCellViewModel(with: $0) } }
```

Notice the `?` after `data`.

The `?` is very important here because it unwraps the optional, and hence `data?.map` calls `map` on the *array*. If you don't have the `?` there, then you are calling [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map), which is an entirely different method.

To remove the `nil` elements from the outer array, you might also want to use `compactMap`:

```
.compactMap { $0.data?.map { IdentifiersCellViewModel(with: $0) } }
```